# Try Catch missing variables in Python

Tags: python, try-catch

I am building a python code that takes inputs from other source which I  can not control.

That source sends some variables, but if some variables are missing then it does not send them at all.

Case 1: VariableName = 5

Case 2:

In my Python code I then do the following to make sure that I do not get error when I try to use missing variables.

```
try: VariableName
except NameError: VariableName= 0
else: VariableName=VariableName
```

Now, if I have 100 of these variables, how can I avoid writing this try catch statement multiple times? I can not think of a way to write it in some function or loop because all of these solutions first evaluate the variable and then go to try catch and this will throw an error if my variable does not exist.

Comment: There is no way to do that by writing a function. You must declare your variable to None prior to assign them and then you could. But if the variable is not defined at all, then you can't pass it as a function argument, and so you can't avoid rewriting the same thing N times.

Comment: Yes, sure, I am not insiting on using a function. but rather asking if there is any way to avoid writing multiple try catch statements

Comment: The only way is to write a function, which by definition is the way to avoid writing things multiple times. So defo I think there is noway in the current situation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.